# How to get a type of the variable from the Python's AST?

Tags: python, types, abstract-syntax-tree

Suppose I want to get the type of all variables from the AST tree that I have generated from some source code -- how would I go about doing that?
For example, suppose in my source code I have something like `i = 5`. How would I determine, from the abstract syntax tree, that the type of `i` is integer?

I tried the `type()` function; however, it does not work in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in other posts, there isn't easy way to achieve this without heavy analysis of the syntax tree, for which python ast module provides no facilities.

You can still use logilab's astng[1](http://www.logilab.org/project/logilab-astng), which is the basis for pylint[2](http://www.logilab.org/project/pylint) and provides static inference capabilities.

Here is a quick example :

```
from logilab.astng.builder import ASTNGBuilder
builder = ASTNGBuilder()
astng = builder.string_build('i = 1', __name__, '<string>')
assnode = astng['']
print [(inf.value, type(inf.value)) for inf in assnode.infer()]
```

Of course you'll have to dig the api for more real-life usage. You can still write python-projects@lists.logilab.org for help on this.

Answer (score 2):

As other posters have noted, this isn't so easy in a dynamically typed language.  You can't just trace the assignment back to a static type declaration, as you can in C or Java.

However, one can often make a reasonable determination of the type.

Presumably the scoping rules allow one to determine which i (or which set of i's) might be accessed/updated/bound where the question is asked ("what the type of  at this point in the code?").  Then one can do an analysis of all the values that might be assigned (a particularly trivial case is when i is bound only to a function definition). The upper bound in the type lattice on those types is the "type" of i. Yes, it might be "anything" in some cases, but in most well-written programs even dynamic variables have a "narrow" type intended by the programmer, and often its a primitive langauge type (like, er, "int"). Or the programmer wouldn't be able to reasonably write an algorithm (What, your array index isn't an integer sometimes?).

You need to do some kind of conservative analysis of the program to determine this upperbound type. (You can obviously do the trivial analysis, and conclude useless that a variable can be "any" type).  I think that's an unsatisfactory answer.

The machinery to do all this analysis is pretty complicated (you need global flow analysis and some determination of what can be dynamically loaded to do this really well) and I doubt if Python's AST package does it.

Comment: Hmm, well, suppose the AST I got, from a node of the code at a certain point of time is:
"a = 2"
Module([Assign([Name('a', Store())], Num(2))...
As you can see, the AST seems to show that type of the value assigned is num -- is there any way or function that I can use on that node in order to get this?

Comment: "What, your array index isn't an integer sometimes?" In some code I've written that can happen, because my array sometimes isn't a `list`, it's a `dict`.

Comment: @Nonomous: well, its clear at *that* point in the code the "type" of a is literally "two" (a subset of nat, a subset of int, a subset of rational, a subset of real, a subset of imaginary, ...).  I don't know Python or the AST module, but your determine of the type of "a" at that point by examining the expression.  You're in trouble when it says,  "a=a+1" unless you examine all the other values of a that dataflow to this point.  You need a dataflow analysis module.  I doubt it is part of the AST module for Python. Somebody else may have built it, but they'll have to speak up.

Comment: @Ben: For Python, you have to worry about your case, but I think my point was clear.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Your point is clear, and you're quite right that in most Python code a given variable will only ever contain values of one type, or perhaps one of a few types. But you have to do full-program analysis to observe that, and even then the places where a variable really could have almost any type means that anything touching that could have almost any type, and so on until it taints huge portions of the program. And for any program with conditional imports or dynamic class creation you need to solve the halting problem just to **enumerate** all the types in the program.

Comment: Yep. Thought I made that point, too.  In fact, there's two kinds of outcomes you are likely to get:  a) its easy to analyze *this* varible, and b) that variable is *really* hard. But static analysis is always about reasoning through a turing machine, and providing as useful an answer as you can get. You can't quit just because its hard; you can only reaonably say, "can't tell you much in this circumstance".

Comment: More importantly, the point is that you can sometimes get a good answer.

Comment: @IraBaxter: *nods* I don't actually disagree with anything you've said. I think we just have different estimations of how much is included in that "sometimes you can get a good answer". My expectation is that it would be a major undertaking (as in PhD thesis topic) to get anything significantly better than telling you the types of names that are bound to constants.

Comment: Um, check my bio and what I do for living... our tools do things like this (not for Python, but global analysis for very big programs)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because Python's variables **don't have** a type. **Values** have types.

That's how dynamic typing works.